# Definir um atributo abstrato numa classe não abstrata

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes-abstratas, static

Eu quero ser capaz de instanciar uma classe funcionário (por isso esta não pode ser abstrata) e ter um atributo salário abstrato que será estático para cada tipo de funcionário.

Posso fazer (na classe funcionario):

```
private abstract int salario;
```

e nas suas subclasses:

```
private static int salario = x,
```

sendo x o valor que eu quero que seja para cada subclasse?

Comment: Você está no stack em português. Traduza sua pergunta.

Comment: Não pode, mas se explicar qual a razão para querer fazer isso talvez seja possível encontrar uma  alternativa.

Comment: Você sabe que se instanciar `Gerente` e que se `Gerente` herdar de `Funcionario`, então você estará instanciando um `Funcionario`, confere?

Answer (score 1):

Se a intenção for impedir o setSalario() você pode colocar o método setSalario como privado e chamar ele junto ao método setCargo()

Exemplo

```
public class Funcionario{
    private float salario;
    private String cargo;

    public void setCargo(String cargo){
        this.cargo = cargo;
        setSalario();
    }

    private void setSalario(){
        if(this.cargo.equals("nomeDoCargo"){
            this.salario = <valor>;
        }
        else if(...){
           ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Assim você protege o salário e só permite que altere se mudar o cargo.